# В Safari не работают tinkerbin.com и jsfiddle.net. У всех так?

Tags: safari, браузер

Думаю многие веб-разработчики знают эти сайты. В IE, Opera, Firefox, Chrome эти сайты нормально работаю. А в сафари постоянно перезагружаются. Это у всех так? Может можно что-то с этим сделать?

Нормально в Сафари работает только cssdesk.com.

Answer (score 1):

Проверил Safari v5.1.2 эти сайты работают.
Удали полностью и поставь заново.

Comment: А какая у вас операционка? У меня Windows 7, версия сафари 5.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

iPod 4 Touch полёт нормальный))